# How do I filter a string the right way to receive included content?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this string in python

```
{ "rval": 0, "param_size": 4, "param": [ 8, 0, 0, 0 ], "session_id": 4 }
```

How do I filter this string the right way to receive the number that is 8 in this example?

All numbers and parameters can change

My approach

```
re.findall('"param": (.+) }',data)[0]
```

but it outputs

```
[ 8, 0, 0, 0 ], "session_id": 4
```

and not 8

Comment: Looks like a dictionary to me, not a string.

Answer (score 5):

Don't even bother with regexing it. Turn the string to a Python dictionary (with the `json` or `literal_eval` modules) then simply `d['param'][0]`.

```
from ast import literal_eval

string = '{"rval": 0, "param_size": 4, "param": [ 8, 0, 0, 0 ], "session_id": 4 }'

d = literal_eval(string)
print(d['param'][0])
# 8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import ast, json
text = '{ "rval": 0, "param_size": 4, "param": [ 8, 0, 0, 0 ], "session_id": 4 }'
```

Json:

```
dict1 = json.loads(text)
dict1["param"][0]
```

Eval:

```
dict2 = ast.literal_eval(text)
dict2["param"][0]
```

Both of two method will convert string to python dict object, and you can access this dict object by `dict[key]`

I tested all the code in python2, I believe there are some illegal character in you text, so I recommend using regex:

```
import re

text = '{ "rval": 0, "param_size": 4, "param": [ 8, 0, 0, 0 ], "session_id": 4 }'

match = re.search(r'"param": \[ (\d+),', text)
match.group(1)
```

out:

```
'8'
```

Comment: for the json: http://pastebin.com/CPgmbCAS for the eval:   
http://pastebin.com/rH9L2zUz